# How to center copyrights text in subfooter?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, copyright-display

I'm using wordpress and the theme is Newspaper. I want to center the copyrights text but I don't know how. I have checked the theme panel settings and there's no options to edit that.

Theme panel pic:[image]

I have gone through some answers in the web and they suggested adding codes in the editor but I'm not sure if it's the footer.php or style.css. If the latter, I managed to find the part regarding sub-footer:

```
    Sub Footer
*/
.td-sub-footer-container {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  /* responsive portrait phone */
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-sub-footer-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
  }
}
.td-sub-footer-copy {
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/* Sub Footer Menu */
.td-sub-footer-container .td-sub-footer-menu {
  float: right;
  /* responsive portrait phone */
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-sub-footer-container .td-sub-footer-menu {
    float: none;
  }
}
.td-subfooter-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  /* responsive landscape tablet */
  /* responsive landscape tablet */
  /* responsive portrait tablet */
  /* responsive portrait phone */
}
@media (min-width: 1019px) and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .td-subfooter-menu {
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1018px) {
  .td-subfooter-menu {
    padding-right: 48px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .td-subfooter-menu {
    float: none;
  }
}
.td-subfooter-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.td-subfooter-menu li a {
  margin-right: 16px;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ccc;
}
.td-subfooter-menu li a:hover {
  color: #4db2ec;
}
.td-subfooter-menu li:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.td-subfooter-menu ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for such depth! Here's some CSS you need to add:

```
.td-pb-span5.td-sub-footer-copy {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The reason why you need this is because your subfooter is following some rules that are already established for the rest of your page:

```
.td-pb-row [class*="td-pb-span"] {
    display: block;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Simply removing the immediately above CSS will 'break' the rest of your page's layout.

### Edit, to answer comment question:

Apologies, here's a bit more information:

When CSS is being applied to an element *that is already being styled by a different selector's rules*, there's a calculation of **specificity**. The CSS I've given you will be fine on its own if added, however, if you'd like to add it to the selector you already have, `.sub-footer-copy`, then you'd have to add !important to override your already written CSS, like so:

```
td.sub-footer-copy{
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is because the selector `.td-pb-row [class*="td-pb-span"]` is more **specific** than the selector `.sub-footer-copy`. Here's some further reading on this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Also, I'd like to note that the selector `.td-pb-row [class*="td-pb-span"]` is **an attribute selector** referring to a CSS class, so it is similar to `.td-pb-row .td-pb-span`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get it. Should I add the code to the one that starts with: ".td-sub-footer-copy" or it's a new one? And if it's new where is the exact location? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies - You can do either. I'll edit my answer a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, side question regarding adding code in style.css editor, it takes a long time (minutes) to scroll down and it crashes a lot, any chance you know how can that be fixed?

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't move, then I added <margin: 0 auto;> and it moved to the center.

Comment: Goodness! I wrote that in inspector but I never copied it over to my answer! Sorry! I will edit that in to my answer for future readers.